# Re-imaged my machine & now web project won't run

Tags: asp.net, session-state

Since I re-imaged my machine I haven't been able to debug an old web project with out getting an error.

When it hits the line:

```
Page.ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID
```

It throws the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in    App_Web_902sorzv.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Session state can only be used when  enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
```

**Additional Info**

- Originally a 2.0 project that was upgraded to 3.5
- Project still runs fine on VM made from image of the old machine
- Added enableSessionState="true" to the pages property in the web.cofig - enablesessionstate
- Site runs fine as it is in TFS on Windows Server R2
- aspnet.config and applicationhost.config in IISExpress are equivalent on both the new machine and VM
- Web project has been upgraded in Visual Studio over time 2005-2008-2010-2012
- Both new machine and VM are Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012 (VM also has VS 2008 installed)

What am I missing that will allow me to debug the old application on the new set up?

Comment: The error is always present or throw only when you try to debug the code?

Comment: Considering that a lot of changes happened to your machine already, try to create a simple asp.net project and see whether the same would run in debug mode. There could be a lot of other reasons why you are unable to debug.

Comment: @bdn02 - Thanks for the nudge, w/out debug I get a Validation of viewstate MAC failed. - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055

Answer (score 0):

I had the application pool set to integrated pipeline instead of classic. Missed that when I did the diff of the applicationhost.config files.

This can be accessed by hitting F4 while the web project is highlighted.